# Typescript rest parameter to accept undefined

Tags: typescript

I have an exercise on Function parameter that I'm still couldn't figure it out:

The maximum function below has an incorrect type. Modify the rest parameter's type to allow undefined in the rest arguments. You won't need to change the function body; its if conditional already ignores undefined values.

```
function maximum(...numbers: Array<number>) {
  let max = -Infinity;
  for (const n of numbers) {
    if (n !== undefined && n > max) {
      max = n;
    }
  }
  return max;
}
```

I tried to modified it as below but still getting a wrong answer. Is there any way else I can change the type to accept undefined?

```
function maximum(...numbers: Array<number> | undefined) {
    let max = -Infinity;
    for(const n of numbers) {
        if(n !== undefined  && n > max) {
            max = n;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: `function maximum(...numbers: Array<number | undefined> )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rest parameter MUST be an array

```
// pseudocode
type FunctionArguments<Rest extends Array<any>>
```

Thus you need

```
function maximum(...numbers: Array< ( number | undefined ) >)
```

Comment: Thank you! never thought I could put an optional in Array type